# is it possible to debug android in emulator with no admin privileges?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using visual studio 2019 to develop a xamarin android application. I would like to debug in an emulator, when I try to open the android device manager, I am prompted for admin credentials. I am using a normal user accout, so I would like to know if there is some way to mange the android emulaltors with this kind of account (no admin).

Thanks.

Comment: You could check the link below. It would be helpful. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/996287/cannot-see-android-emulators-as-non-admin-user.html

Comment: It doesn't work. I have installed the VS 2022 and I still need to use an administrator account to can start the emultator.

Comment: Do you have the administrator account? Is this your office PC? If yes, maybe there are some limitations from your company. Just contact you IT.